# can't find element in protractor

Tags: html, dom, protractor, e2e-testing

need your help.

I'm running a test which performing registration to the website and then checking the details that entered (first name, last name etc)
in order to do it, after the registration I'm going to the account settings and checking the text in the inputs elements (to be equal to the entered details).
the problem is that I keep getting

```
 ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

which means the protractor can't see the elements I'm referring to.
it looks like for some reason the protractor is not really at the same page.
when using the element explorer- I do get the results.
I've tried to check other elements (such as 'h1') - and it doesn't find it either.

this is an example:
the markup:

```
<input data-ng-model="account.firstName" id="accountFirstName" name="accountFirstName" type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-animate ng-invalid-remove ng-valid-add ng-invalid-required-remove ng-invalid-remove-active ng-valid ng-valid-add-active ng-invalid-required-remove-active ng-valid-required" required="" style="">
```

in protractor:

```
element(by.name('accountFirstName')).getAttribute('value').then(function (firstNameAccount) {
   expect(firstNameAccount).toEqual(firstName);
```

any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: If you're saying you're not at the right page, that's probably the reason. Can you provide the commands you used in element explorer that worked, and what the code for your test look like